# Название профессии людей в образах знаменитостей

Tags: названия, профессии

Речь о тех, кто в одежде Сталина, Ленина, Петра или известных персонажей фотографируется за деньги на улице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, это специализирующиеся на таких образах (уличные) **аниматоры**, работающие для взрослой аудитории:

http://web.snauka.ru/issues/2012/02/8987

Answer (score 0):

В словаре синонимов слову «клоун» приводится в соответствие «клоун – знаменитость». Сейчас у циркового клоуна много специализаций, но своим названием он обязан самой первой - пародист, пересмешник, подражатель. Заметим, что слова «клоун» и «клон» не только созвучны, но и схожи по смыслу, поскольку «клон», это генетическая копия, близнец, двойник.

Отсюда, название занятия людей, копирующих образы популярных личностей: клон знаменитости  или клоун – знаменитьсть.